# Nested Regular Expression in Python for

Tags: python, regex, nested

Is there a way to do nested regular expression in Python?
For example I have

```
r1 = re.compile(r'SO ON')
```

can I have something like

```
r2 = re.compile(r'WHATEVER AND (r1)*')
```

to validate "WHATEVER AND SO ON" for this example.

I tried finding about this around but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Does making each pattern a string and concatenating them not work?

Comment: Yeah but that might be limited functionality to what a string can hold..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r1 = re.compile(r'SO ON')
r2 = re.compile(r'WHATEVER AND (%s)*' % r1.pattern)
```

This isn't actually using any special feature of regex, it's using [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). Multiple strings can be passed in as:

```
r'WHATEVER AND (%s) (%s)' % (r1.pattern, 'hello')
```

Comment: Thanks. I know about * to give random example to the question and what the ability of the nested regex is. Will accept when available. Thank you!

Comment: #U2EF1 What would be the syntax to do more than one regex? Or is that not possible?

    r2 = re.compile(r'WHATEVER AND (%s)*' % r1.pattern, % r3.pattern)

Comment: I feel a moral obligation to point out that this example uses *old-style* string formatting, and the wave of the future in python is to use *new-style* string formatting, as in `r2 = re.compile(r'WHATEVER AND ({})*'.format(r1.pattern))`  There are many reasons why this is superior to the *old-style* syntax.  To read them look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

Answer (score 0):

I feel a moral obligation to point out that this is strictly supportive of regexen with no flags. As soon as you start using flags like re.MULTILINE this approach does not work. Perl was great with regex inside regex. I wish I could find a good Python solution.