# Regex , extract specific pattern and get the highest value out of them

Tags: python, regex

String = `xxxx 100.00 10.1000 2000.00 yyyy`

What is the best way to extract floats/numbers from here, add them to an array, and return back the highest value?

To get value, we can use `(\d+[.,]\d+\d+)`, BUT not 100% sure how to get these values ONLY with the following logic:

1. Values should go in the row with space-delimited, overwise ignore pattern
2. Values could follow these patterns - `(\d+[.,]\d+\d+)` or `(\d+[.,]\d+[.,]\d+)`
3. Return back the highest value

I think it should be something better than --  `(\d+[.,]\d+\d+) (\d+[.,]\d+\d+) (\d+[.,]\d+\d+)`

E.G. Ideally...

If we have this string `xxxx 100.00 10.1000 2000.00 yyyy xxxx 100.00 5000.1000 2000.00 yyyy xxxx 90000.00 10.1000 2000.00 yyyy`

I would like to make it like this
`xxxx 2000.00 yyyy xxxx 5000.1000 yyyy xxxx 90000.00 yyyy`

Comment: if the code works, it is good. ‘premature optimization is the root of all evil’.

Comment: You can use `r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+"`

Comment: @LeiYang this is not "premature optimization" this is more about how to make it more generic, + by using the simplest way to get the result, I the way which I'm currently doing... looks horrible in my eyes .. and I thought someone with better experience can suggest something...

Comment: if i were you, i'd rather find numbers string, then use `split()`

Comment: @Pygirl Have updated quest with example

Comment: @LeiYang, have updated the quest with the example, which show better, what exactly I would like to do.... it is more get the highest number from the set.... when the string  could be massive

Comment: @OksanaOk Is it always three numbers between `xxxx` and `yyyy`?

Comment: @AmalK nope, this is just an example... it could be random text/values... and I need to focus ONLY on these sets of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

With

```
import re

re_float = re.compile(r'[-+]?(?:(?:\d+,)+\d+\.\d+|(?:\d+,)+\d+|\d+\.\d+|\d+)')
re_float_group = re.compile(f' (?:{re_float.pattern} )+')

def max_float_str(m):
    return f" {max(float(n.replace(',', '')) for n in re_float.findall(m.group()))} "
```

this

```
print(re_float_group.findall(s))
print(re_float_group.sub(max_float_str, s))
```

leads to:

```
[' 100.00 10.1000 2000.00 ', ' 100.00 5000.1000 2000.00 ', ' 90000.00 10.1000 2000.00 ']
'xxxx 2000.0 yyyy xxxx 5000.1 yyyy xxxx 90000.0 yyyy'
```

for

```
s = 'xxxx 100.00 10.1000 2000.00 yyyy xxxx 100.00 5000.1000 2000.00 yyyy xxxx 90000.00 10.1000 2000.00 yyyy'
```

etc.

Certainly far from perfect, and I'm sure it has to be tuned, but maybe you can use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re
string 'xxxx 100.00 10.1000 2000.00 yyyy' 
max(map(float,re.findall(r"\d*\.?\d+|\d+",string)))
```

Comment: This is great !! But I will need to find the highest from the set of value, when string could be massive and set of values can exist multiple times

Comment: @OksanaOk There must be some pattern right? Like I want to replace the string with the highest number if those string is in between some words/symbols or characters

Comment: Sadly no.... :D This is why I'm here....  I need to find three value in the row with space-delimited (with any random text/value between ...) and get the highest out of them and replace it back... (I have showed what si the input and output in example)

Comment: @OksanaOk: You have to write multiple regex pattern. 1st use it to get the numerical values within two words/letters. find all the groups. then for each group extract the numbers and replace the whole string with the highest number. This will give you some hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122385/nested-regular-expression-in-python-for